# avoiding the first space on split the array of first string

Tags: javascript

how can i split the below string into a required array by avoiding the first space of the first string.

below is the sample snippet, i tried to split it  with space but since first **item 1** itself having a space. How can i avoid it and take as a single element.

```js
const data = "Item 1 10 200"

// required format [item 1, 10, 200]

// what i tried is 
const implemented = data.split(" ")
console.log(implemented)
```

Comment: Split on `\t` which is what is separating your items

Comment: Does your `data` has constant number of spaces between separate parts in the `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split()` by **[\t](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_tab.asp)**

```js
let data = "Item 1 10 200"
data = data.split("\t");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Alternatively vote this up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537773/295783

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the "space" between items from your question is a tab

```js
console.log(
"Item 1 10 200".split('\t')
) //['Item 1', '10', '200']
```

Answer (score 3):

In your given example, the delimiter is \t (horizontal tab); so you can do like so,

```js
const data = "Item 1 10 200"
const implemented = data.split(/\t/)
console.log(implemented)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string contains tabs instead of space so:

```js
const data = "Item 1 10 200"

const implemented = data.split("\t")
console.log(implemented)
```

Comment: Please don't post TWO answers just because the first one was voted down. Also already answered

Comment: I deleted first answer

Comment: Alternatively vote this up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54537773/295783

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. It was not there by the time I posted this answer so I did not see it. Upvoted.